# Azure IoT Hub InvalidProtocolVersion

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

it seems like I have to get something really wrong on the Azure IoT Hub.
I want to send a basic rest request to try testing it out.

I used postman for it and I already generated the SAS Token.

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV0Sr.png)

My URI is "https://xxxxx.azure-devices.net/devices/xxxxx/messages/api-version=2021-04-18". The first question would be where do I find my API-version? I saw that part in many other posts yet I don´t know where to find the information. So I just decided to fill in the date where I created the instances.

My Second Question would be how should I classify the SAS Token in the header? Is Authentification the right parameter?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answers to your question in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#common-parameters-and-headers) of the docs.

- Replace {api-version} with "2018-06-30" in the URI.
- Set the Authorization header to a SAS token created as specified in the
  security tokens section of [Using IoT Hub security tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security).

Comment: Have set the API version & also generate saas token with 1 year of validity but giving me the same issue with the postman

Comment: @KaranEkkawala feel free to create a new question, you might be facing a different issue.

Comment: Thanks but the issues was resolved, there is a content type issue on the header

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the SAS Token?
Ensure to set right policy when generating the SAS token as well as an expiry time in the future, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#security-tokens

Azure CLI IoT generated tokens have a default validity of 1 hour and validity can be extended by the --duration parameter.