# Azure IoT Hub Rest API returns "InvalidProtocolVersion;Bad Request"

Tags: azure, rest, azure-iot-hub

I'm new to Azure IoT Hub

What I'm trying to do is remove pending commands for a device in the IoT Hub by using Azure IoT Hub's REST API as shown here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/cloud-to-device-messages/purge-c)

But I keep getting the same error **"InvalidProtocolVersion;Bad Request"**

[see this postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/extra.png)

I added a SAS Token in the header and changed the *api-version* parameter but nothing works.

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added a SAS Token in the header and changed the api-version parameter but nothing works.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#common-parameters-and-headers):

- DELETE operations may include the following header: `If-Match = [*|<etag from get>]`

Alternatively, you can use the following [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/device/c2d-message?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-device-c2d-message-purge) Azure CLI command to purge cloud-to-device message queue for a target device:

```
az iot device c2d-message purge --device-id
                                [--hub-name]
                                [--login]
                                [--resource-group]
```

**Updated answer:**

According to [Eyasu Bogale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18954418/eyasu-bogale):

> SAS token did not have all the permission it needed. Generated it using `az iot hub generate-sas-token -n roboatiothub --policy iothubowner` (not **registryRead**) and now it works (even without the If-Match header)

References: [Azure IoT Hub InvalidProtocolVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67147004/azure-iot-hub-invalidprotocolversion),[Control access to IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security) and [az iot hub generate-sas-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-generate-sas-token)

Comment: My Sas Token did not have all the permission it needed. 

i generated it like this 

`az iot hub generate-sas-token -n roboatiothub --policy **iothubowner** (and not **registryRead**)`
and now it works (even without the If-Match header)

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved the issue. Updated the answer.